# StringTokenizer is not getting right value after delimiter

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the string from ARCHIVE_FILE_EXTENSION_FILTER but somehow it is not taking the first value and returning NULL

Below is the properties info

```
#indicate any file extensions to filter by - must be comma-delimited. Enter 'none' to get all files
Text.FileArchiver.INV_ARCHIVE_FILE_EXTENSION_FILTER=done , proc
```

May I know why it's not working the value and any issue with my code

[image]

```
String extension = env.getProperty(trimIni(ARCHIVE_FILE_EXTENSION_FILTER));

        if (Objects.nonNull(extension) && !NONE.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(extension, ",");
            int i = 0;
            String[] tmpExtensions = {};

            if (token.countTokens() > 0) {
                tmpExtensions = new String[token.countTokens()];
            }

            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tmpExtensions[i] = token.nextToken();
            }

            extensions = tmpExtensions;
        }
```

Comment: `i = 0;` and is never updated, so why did you expect `tmpExtensions[i]` to ever update anything but the first slot in the array?

Comment: From the javadoc of [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): *"`StringTokenizer` is a **legacy** class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its **use is discouraged in new code**. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."* --- So why aren't you using `extensions = extension.split(",");` to replace those 10 lines of code with a simple 1-liner that does the same?

Comment: Hi @Andreas this works and thanks for th advice and recommendation.Apperciate it